# Springboot Asynchronous Data Fetching from External API

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm working on a project using React.js for the front end and Spring Boot for the back end. I need to query data from an external API, which in some cases can take several seconds to return a response. So, I need a way to update the UI with the data returned by the API, but without blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use a message broker like kafka and send your request on a topic like REQUEST_TOPIC. Then write a consumer that calls your target api and get response and then send this response on another topic like RESPONSE_TOPIC.

For your front end update you should write a websocket which get datas from RESPONSE_TOPIC  and send it to the registered user on the websocket.

All of this process is async and is nonblocking .

you can find the way to write a sample websocket in this url

https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring